# WPF ObservableCollection change property at once

Tags: c#, wpf, observablecollection

I am working with an ObservableCollection with a binding to checkboxes in the UI created in a ComboBox this way:

```
<CheckBox IsChecked="{Binding Path=theItemIsSelected, Mode= TwoWay}" Margin="0,0,4,0" />
```

In this case, "theItemIsSelected" is a boolean, just a flag to indicate that the item is selected or not. When enabled/disabled some items in another list (let's call it "*main list*") are displayed/hidden on a main Listview.

The fact is that if the "*main list*" contains several elements, the UI is updated slowly when if the flag `theItemIsSelected` is enabled one by one. This piece of code is called when the user presses a "Select all" checkbox:

```
if (this.myObsCol != null) 
{
    for (int i = 0; i < this.myObsCol.Count; i++)
    {
        //This line allows to display the elements in the main list
         this.myObsCol[i].theItemIsSelected = true;
    }
}
```

Is there any cleaner way to do this so as the elements in the main list are displayed faster?

Thanks.

Comment: try this :this.myObsCol.Select(ob=>ob.theItemIsSelected = true);

Answer (score 1):

You can use parallel LINQ for this scenario:

```
if (this.myObsCol != null) 
{
    myObsCol.AsParallel()
            .ForAll(x => x.theItemIsSelected = true);
}
```